# Get property from reader.io object in golang

Tags: http, go

I'm new at golang and got some little problem:

I got remoteApi that give me some response when I'm making http request like here:

```
res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
```

the body of the response contains some json such as :

```
{
a: 'hello'
b: 5
c:[1,2,3]
}
```

I need to assign the value of "a" to other variable .
What is the best way to access one of res.Body properties? Ive tried to convert to json / string and so but no success

thanks

Comment: What have you tried? There are countless examples of unmarshaling JSON in Go.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var s struct {
    A string
}
err := json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&s)
// check err
result := s.A
```

Also please note that your JSON response example is not valid JSON (single quotes instead of double quotes, field names are not quoted, field separators missing) and will not be parsed successfully as such.